# Filter by pills/buttons instead of using a select - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I'm building with Angular and have used a filter pipe to filter on the selected option from my dropdown on the `*ngFor` loop. The content then filters accordingly. I want to swap the select options to buttons or pills. So when a button is clicked the filter takes place - the button will act as a on/off switch so you can have more than one option filtered.

Here is my stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-tyle1f

```
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <select class="form-control" name="locationFilter" id="locationFilter" [(ngModel)]="filteredLocation">
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique" value="{{entry.location}}">{{entry.location}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
//Button filters below
       <div ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="filteredLocation" name="locationFilter" id="locationFilter">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique">{{entry.location}}</button>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure how to get the buttons to work the same way as no filtering takes place.... any help appreciated!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter on multiple options your filter pipe will have to be adjusted to accomadate an array of strings to filter on.

So in your `FilterPipe` the transform function gets changed as follows:

```
transform(value: string[], filterStrings: string[], propName: string): any {
    if (value.length === 0 || !filterStrings || filterStrings.length === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const resultArray = [];
    for (const item of value) {
      if (filterStrings.indexOf(item[propName]) >= 0) {
        resultArray.push(item)
      }
    }

    return resultArray;
}
```

After that you need to add some code to the `timeline.component.ts` file:

An array to hold all the active filter options:

```
filteredLocations: string[] = [];
```

A function to toggle an option on or off:

```
toggle(location) {
    let indexLocation = this.filteredLocations.indexOf(location);
    if (indexLocation >= 0) {
      this.filteredLocations = this.filteredLocations.filter((i) => i !== location);
    } else {
      this.filteredLocations.push(location);
    }
}
```

Now change the template (`timeline.component.html`):

Remove the selection box.

Add a click handler to your button:

```
<button (click)="toggle(entry.location)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique">{{entry.location}}</button>
```

Lastly, the filter should accept the new filtered locations: (I just changed filteredLocation to filteredLocations)

```
*ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filter:filteredLocations:'location'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind a click event `(click)="filteredLocation = entry.location"` to the button

Try like this:

```
 <div ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="filteredLocation" name="locationFilter" id="locationFilter">
     <button  (click)="filteredLocation = entry.location" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique">{{entry.location}}</button>
  </div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-bqa62j?embed=1&file=src/app/timeline/timeline.component.html)**

Answer (score 3):

The crux of  this is just assign the value of the button/switch to your `filteredLocation` variable like below

```
<button (click)="filteredLocation = entry.location" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique">{{entry.location}}</button>
```

[Updated Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-jrik7m)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas how I can change the filter/pipe to take more than one filter at a time?

Comment: You can apply more than one filters/pipe easily just pipe them with `|` and they will be applied in the sequence of application. As in output of first pipe will be input for the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Easier to just have a click handler:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique" (click)="filter(entry)">{{entry.location}}</button>
</div>

filter(entry) {
  this.filteredLocation = entry.location;
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-z2e6zh?file=src/app/timeline/timeline.component.ts